# In Openmp is there a way to find out the place to which the master thread is assigned?

Tags: c++, openmp

With openmp's thread affinity mechanisms, the master thread is assigned to the place where the parent of the master thread is running (where the set of places is specified by OMP_PLACES). It is my understanding that effectively this means that the OS determines the place where the master thread gets executed. Is there a way to find from inside your C++ code the actual place or hardware thread to which this master thread is binded? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `omp_get_place_num()`?
The [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-1.pdf) states:

> The **omp_get_place_num** routine returns the place number of the place to
> which the encountering thread is bound.

Another possibility is to set the `OMP_DISPLAY_AFFINITY` environment variable to **true** which will cause the affinity information to be displayed.